# Is it normal to pass many interfaces in ViewModel constructor using DI container in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a huge WPF project. It uses:

- MVVM Light
- Microsoft.Unity container as a ViewModelLocator

The MainView content depends from other UserControls:

```
<ContentControl  Visibility="Visible"
                 Content="{Binding ContentViewModel}" />
```

Each ViewModel for content creates by ConcreateViewModelFactory:

```
 ContentViewModel =(SimpleViewModelBase)  _extendedSearchVMFactory.CreateInstance();
```

All ViewModels factories has interfaces that registered in ViewModelLocator.
Factory example:

```
public class MainViewModelFactory : IMainViewModelFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public MainViewModelFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public MainViewModel CreateInstance(df_role[] currentRoles)
    {
        var vm = _container.Resolve<MainViewModel>(
            new ParameterOverride("currentRoles", currentRoles));
        return vm;
    }
}
```

MainViewModel costructor has about 40 parameters to keep all Interfaces for ViewModel constructors:

```
public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService,
        IDialogService dialogService,
        ISearchByIdViewModelFactory searchViewModelFactory,
        ISearchByPhonesViewModelFactory searchByPhonesViewModelFactory,
        IDoubleSearcherViewModelFactory doubleSearcherViewModelFactory,
        IAnalysisOfDoubleSearchAlgorythmViewModelFactory analysisOfDoubleSearchAlgorythmViewModelFactory,...
```

My question: How can I refactor this? If you have helpful information about DI+MVVM I will be grateful.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: If it takes 40 parameters probably it does a lot of work. You need to separate the responsibilities and move group of objects to a separate class. Then you can inject the newly created collaborator to your `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Well going by your title _"Is it normal to pass many interfaces in ViewModel constructor using DI container in WPF"_ - WPF has **no dependency** (no pun intended) on DI so _"Is it normal"_ would have to depend on your choice of a DI system.  I don't know much about the DI you are using, but if you were using Microsoft MEF then your constructor would be normally parameter-less.  MEF injects values into properties, not into constructors.  40 parameters would strike me as a sign of bad design on your part

Comment: As the others have said, separate the responsibility of the view model into services, and have those injected instead. That way, you may only need to inject a max of 5 services. This should also make the view model easier to unit test.

Comment: I agree with @SriramSakthivel. Check out [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainViewModel constructor has many parameters. MainViewModel violates "Single Responsibility Principle". Ideally any class should not have many responsibility.

Please go through the links below to understand **Single Responsibility Principle.**

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles using-simple-Csharp

   The link #1 talks about SOLID Architecture Principle

   SOLID stands for:
   "S" - SRP (Single responsibility principle)
   “O” - Open closed principle
   “L”- LSP (Liskov substitution principle)
   “I” - ISP (Interface Segregation principle)
   “D” - Dependency inversion principle.

**MVVM:** To understand MVVM, please go through the link below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: That isn't entirely true... I could have a main menu view-model that had 100 view-models injected into it... and its sole responsibility is to allow (view) buttons to be bound to those injected view-models (and open their view). In other words, lots of constructor args, in itself, is not indicative of violating Single Responsibility.

Comment: @MeirionHughes - In my opinion, lots of constructor argument also makes design difficult to unit test. We should also keep "design for testability" in mind.

Comment: I know SOLID princples and I try to follow these rules, but now, i want to find a good way. Your link about MVVM pattern is in my bookmarks =) Thanks for your answer!